# Extracting data out of a recursive function using tuples

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, tuples

I have a Scala function that does 2-3 recursive calls through its lifetime. I want to save the variable inside the second tuple in a list. Is there a smart way to do this?

Just passing the variable around would mean that I would have a List[String], when in actuality what I want is a List[List[String]].

Would there be a need for a variable inside the function that updated with each itteration?

```
def someRecursiveFunction(listOfWords:List[String])List[List[String]] = {
   val textSplitter = listOfWords.lastIndexOf("Some Word")
   if (Some Word != -1) {
     val someTuple = listofWords.splitAt(textSplitter)
     val valueIwant = someTuple._2
     someRecursiveFunction(someTuple._1)
   }
 List(someTuple._2,someTuple._2(1),someTuple._2(2)) // What I want back
}
```

Is there a way to extract the second tuple out of the recursive function so that I can use it further on in my program?

Comment: Hi @Asilux, could you make your question more concise? - I'm not sure what you want and what is the problem. Also, could you provide an example input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If the return type is fixed to be `List[List[String]]`, the following changes to be made
to the code :

1. Because `someType._2` is accessed as `someType._2(2)`, there should be at least 
   `3` strings in `someType._2` list.
2. The last expression to be must of return type ie., `List[List[String]]`. Because `someType._2(1)` 
   and `someType._2(2)` are just strings and not `List[String]`: 
   `List(someTuple._2,List(someTuple._2(1),someTuple._2(2)))` will be of return type
   `List[List[String]]`
3. The value of "`Some Word`" will be changing in the recursive process duly noting 
   that the `someTuple._2.size` is always `>=3`.
4. As we need to access `someType._2` and it will be changing during each recursion,
   it is declared as `var` within the recursive function.

   With this understanding drawn from your requirement, the following code may be
   what you are looking for:

   ```
    def someRecursiveFunction(listOfWords:List[String],sw: String):List[List[String]] = {
      val textSplitter = listOfWords.lastIndexOf(sw)
      var i =0
      if(i==0) { var someTuple:(List[String],List[String]) = (List(),List()) }
      if (textSplitter != -1 && listOfWords.size-3>=textSplitter) {
        someTuple = listOfWords.splitAt(textSplitter)
        println(someTuple._1,someTuple._2)  // for checking recursion
      if( someTuple._1.size>=3){ i+=1
        someRecursiveFunction(someTuple._1,someTuple._1(textSplitter-3))}
      }          
      List(someTuple._2,List(someTuple._2(1),someTuple._2(2))) // What I want back
    }
   ```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
val list = List("a","b","c","x","y","z","k","j","g","Some Word","d","e","f","u","m","p")


scala> val list = List("a","b","c","x","y","z","k","j","g","Some Word","d","e","f","u","m","p")
list: List[String] = List(a, b, c, x, y, z, k, j, g, Some Word, d, e, f, u, m, p)

scala> someRecursiveFunction(list,"d")
(List(a, b, c, x, y, z, k, j, g, Some Word),List(d, e, f, u, m, p))
(List(a, b, c, x, y, z, k),List(j, g, Some Word))
(List(a, b, c, x),List(y, z, k))
(List(a),List(b, c, x))
res70: List[List[String]] = List(List(b, c, x), List(c, x))

scala> someRecursiveFunction(list,"Some Word")
(List(a, b, c, x, y, z, k, j, g),List(Some Word, d, e, f, u, m, p))
(List(a, b, c, x, y, z),List(k, j, g))
(List(a, b, c),List(x, y, z))
(List(),List(a, b, c))
res71: List[List[String]] = List(List(a, b, c), List(b, c))
```